# confused with lambda and list comprehension

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

So I've been trying some combinations to grasp the logic better. However, I've encountered a few problems.

For example:

```
l1 = [lambda :x for x in range(1,5)]
for k in l1:
    print(k())
```

Here the output is 4,4,4,4 which is the last number of the range, the output is always returns as the last number of the range, I don't understand that. Why is output always the last number of the range?

However, the result comes as expected below, 1,2,3,4

```
for l in range(1,5):
    def test():
        return l
    print(test())
```

Well, if I assign x, output comes as expected, 1,2,3,4

```
l1 = [lambda arg=x:arg for x in range(1,5)]
for k in l1:
    print(k())
```

But If I make expression "x", output returns "4,4,4,4" again. Why is that?

```
l1 = [lambda y=x:x for x in range(1,5)]
for k in l1:
    print(k())
```

Comment: In the last code you probably mean `l1 = [lambda y=x: y for x in range(1, 5)]` (note the `y` inside lambda body)